# How can I remove auto generated headers from a request before sending it in reactor-netty?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

Is it possible to remove all auto generated headers from a request before it is sent in reactor-netty?

I have a use case where i need to remove all auto generated headers in my request. In apache httpclient4 there are intercepters which can be used to remove the headers before request is sent.

Is there some way to do this in reactor-netty?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactor Netty provides [lifecycle callbacks](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_lifecycle_callbacks_4) so that one can intercept the request/response

For your particular question you can use `doOnRequest`, as in the code below:

```
HttpClient.create()
          ...
          .doOnRequest((req, con) -> ...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will work for me